# Error while loading shared libraries while running sqlplus

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, sqlplus

I am trying to install and run sqlplus in my ubuntu machine. I get the above error

```
error while loading shared libraries: libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

when I run

```
sudo sqlplus64 <user>/<pass>@//<ip>:<port>/db
```

despite following the steps mentioned in the oracle install client document https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle%20Instant%20Client

I have correctly set ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH
My strace sqlplus /nolog output shows below error

```
write(2, "SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>"..., 47SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
) = 47
write(2, "SP2-0750: You may need to set OR"..., 76SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
) = 76
```

I can also attach complete strace if needed. Can someone help me fix the issue ?

Comment: So you downloaded instant client from Oracle Website along with the sqlplus executable and set ORACLE_HOME to the path where the client is unziped and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the $ORACLE_HOME/lib?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Alternatively  Downloaded and installed sql developer from oracle from the link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 5):

Here is a shortened version of the process I use when installing the Oracle instant client on my machines:

1 - Get alien `sudo apt-get install alien`

2 - Download the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html) (Download basic, devel, and sqlplus)

3 - Use Alien to install the `.rpm` packages

`sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm`

`sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm`

`sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm`

4 - Navigate to the installation directory for sqlplus `$ cd /usr/lib/oracle/12.X/client64/bin/`

5 - Run sqlplus `$ ./sqlplus` and see if you get an error regarding `libaio1`

6 - You may need to install `libaio1` (`$ sudo apt-get install libaio1`)

7 - If you are still getting module errors, try running [ldd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) `$ ldd sqlplus`.   Install what you need.

8 - Set the following environment variables

`export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/`

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/bin/`

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/`

You can set this for all users in `/etc/bash.bashrc`.  A [discussion of setting environment variables](http://bencane.com/2013/09/16/understanding-a-little-more-about-etcprofile-and-etcbashrc/) for one or many users for different types of shells is outside the realm of this question.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

It looks variables are not set properly or there is no oracle client in folder where variables are set or it has no rights to execute.

Please do in terminal you're going to run sqlplus:

```
echo $ORACLE_HOME
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

If they don't show correct values it means you haven't set variables properly (either export them before runing sqlplus or set them for each terminal session). 
If they show correct value please go to folder check if there are Oracle client files. If yes please check execution rights for files there (`ls -la`). If files have no grants to be open and execute pleaswe add it (`chmod`). If all three are ok client should work.

Comment: Yes the owner was root. Changed it but still getting the error :(